# Impact of global volcano eruption into artificial structures

Tags: science-based, planets, apocalypse, near-future, earth

A suplement to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185166/36) this time targeting human constructions and artificial structures.

Imagine that one day [all Earth volcanoes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185162/36) has erupted [in the same moment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/185164/36). How would running lava, ash and gases blowing from volcanoes impact:

- roads and concrete, stone or brick-based buildings that most of our cities are made of,
- wooden buildings and constructions that you can mostly find in the villages,
- metal structures like railroads, bridges, hanging electric wires,

Is there anything human-made that would have chance surviving such appocalypse?

Comment: This one might be salvageable. If ONE volcano erupted near a city that actually has a volcano (like Yokohama, Japan), what could we expect to happen to the city (just the city, nothing outlying, one of its inhabitants, just the structure of the city). That might, maybe, be narrow enough to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Everything will burn**

Well, most of everything. Assuming all human structures are getting covered in hot volcanic ash, virtually all roofs will catch fire at some point. Next, fire will consume the entire building, while sprinkler systems will fail. Asphalt roads will burn too, if the heat is high. Concrete roads and structures would not burn, but get damaged because of fire. Freestanding metal structures will survive, but if there is a lot of combustive material in or around such structure, they will be destroyed too (remember, World Trade Center was mostly steel and concrete).

Structures with concrete roofs and steel-only hangars will fare the best. They may be spared from destruction by fire and remain mostly intact.